# Lowest Bluetooth audio volume is too loud

Tags: bluetooth-audio, spotify, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I recently acquired a pair of Galaxy Buds to use with my Galaxy S10+. I am using them to listen to Spotify at work.  Everything is working fine except the lowest volume setting is a bit too loud. If I were to turn up the volume to 25% then it would be blasting.

I looked around in the system settings and the Galaxy Wear app settings but I don't see any option to adjust this.

Is there a way to decrease the overall Bluetooth audio volume so the lowest notch isn't so loud?

Comment: If in Developer options, "Disable absolute volume" is enabled, try to disable it.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Thank you for making me aware of that setting. Unfortunately it was already disabled. I played around with it for a bit and didn't notice a difference.

Comment: There are some apps in PlayStore like "Precise Volume" that claim that they can massive increase the number of volume steps which makes it possible to change the volume below the old minimum.

Comment: @Robert I gave the Precise Volume app a shot. It lets you set the volume from 0% to 100% at intervals of 1%, which seemed promising at first. However, on my device, it seems 1% through 9% are the same volume, 10% through 18% are the same volume, etc. So the notches that I'm normally allowed for Bluetooth volume still seem to be enforced.

Comment: Then I would contact Samsung support complain about the volume. As phone and headphones are Samsung products they should provide a solution - or at least learn that something is wrong with their product.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix this by using the Samsung [SoundAssistant](https://galaxystore.samsung.com/detail/com.samsung.android.soundassistant) app.

1. Install app from Galaxy Store.
2. Go to Individual app volumes.
3. Add application.
4. Adjust volume for that app.

Comment: Browsing to the link provided, which is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.soundassistant, resulted in "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server."  So in researching this further I found a built-in method to reduce the volume.  I posted an answer for that heres; https://android.stackexchange.com/a/255971/13886

Answer (score 2):

Under the Spotify settings, switch the volume level setting from normal to quiet and restart the app.

Comment: If anyone has a better answer as to how to reduce the Bluetooth Audio volume across all applications instead of just Spotify, please post it and I will switch the accepted answer to that one.

Comment: This feature is available for Premium accounts only.

Answer (score 0):

I have an MTK Android phone so I don't know if it will work on others (Snapdragon, Exynos, Kirin, etc)

1. Launch MTK Engineer Mode app: MTK settings > Hardware testing (tab) > Audio > Volume > Audio playback
2. Change the selected channel from System to Music.
3. Then experiment by decreasing the values of Index 1

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be phone-specific (my phone is an "Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra") or Android version-specific, but I am posting this answer anyway just in case someone finds it useful:

I had a similar issue with a set of Bluetooth earbuds ([Amazon ASIN B0BPS83P1W](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=B0BPS83P1W)), namely this: Pressing the phones volume button to the lowest level (just one level *above* the level where the sound completely shuts off, or mutes the sound) results in the volume being still too loud for my ears.  I observe that my pair of earbuds is likely different from the OP's earbuds (completely different manufacturer, etc.), so I reason this is an issue that must be rectified in the Android system via app or other means, and might not implicate the bluetooth earbud manufacturer.

I examined [DavidEG's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221945/13886) on 2024-01-27, and particularly the
[SoundAssistant](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.soundassistant) app mentioned in that answer, and found it was non-existent (browsing to that link resulted in "We're sorry, the requested URL was not found on this server."). I then searched through for other apps that might directly allow controlling the effective volume level and did not find any app (I did not purchase any apps but only examined cost-free apps) that could effectively reduce the volume level. There may be apps that can do so, but it was next to impossible to identify them without testing them all, which is prohibitively expensive in time-cost. Thus I gave up on that.

I then hunted through my phones built-in settings and found an **Equalizer** that seemed to work: I found that the levels for all of the frequencies could be lowered. In this particular use-case, I lowered all frequencies down to the same level, as I do not require amplification or attenuation of *different* frequencies but instead attenuate **all** frequencies.

The advantage of this approach is that it does not require installation of apps to address this issue only to find they come with other hidden costs such as ads. The possible disadvantage is that this may be phone-specific or Android-version specific, and if so, your phones customized version of Android may not have a/the so-called "Equalizer" setting.

Regardless, below I show the screenshots of how to navigate down to the Equalizer and lower the volume for all frequencies. Other phones may have similar means to lower the volume globally:

[image: screenshot1] [image: screenshot2]

[image: screenshot3] [image: screenshot4]